# Scheme language increasing order

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to write a code in scheme language. I'm trying to write a function called Order and it will produce true if the integers in a list are in increasing order and false otherwise.

For example:

```
(order? (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 (cons 4 empty)))))
true
(order? (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 (cons 1 empty)))))
false
```

Comment: If you are using `empty`, you must be writing Racket, not standard Scheme. What have you done so far to solve your problem? You should include your best attempt so that others can help; otherwise it seems that you are asking for someone to write code for you. That said, this is a one-liner. You know that `(< 1 2 3 4 5)` --> `#t`. Now fill in the blank: `(define (order-increasing? xs) (_____ < xs))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're expected to solve this with explicit recursion, these are the conditions for a list to be considered ordered:

- The list is empty, *or*
- The list has a single element, *or*
- Its first element is smaller than the second element *and* its tail is ordered.

Translating into Scheme left as an exercise